# In UNIX, what means install the resulting executable?

Tags: unix

This is a question that came to me when I read a [tutorial about UNIX](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix7.html)

In UNIX, we get the software source code, then we compile it to get the resulting executable.

But what means INSTALL THE RESULTING EXECUTABLE?

I think the executable is already something EXECUTABLE by simply double clicking it. It doesn't need to be installed.
Anyone could tell me in details what happens during the installation?(a standard exemple will be really appreciated)

Thanks a lot！

Comment: Depends on the build. Many put the executable into the proper lib directory in your path, etc. Some move ancillary files (such as man pages, etc.)...

Comment: It simply means install it where you want to. You usually want to clean the build dir, so install the executable somewhere and clean the original dir.

Answer (score 1):

The build process, done as an ordinary user, creates an executable binary but doesn't put it someplace that will be found when typed on a command line (without providing the full path, anyway).

"Install" means to copy the binary to wherever you want it.  Common places are `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` but these are not writable by an ordinary user; you must use root permissions to copy them there which is why the build (done as you) couldn't make it happen (even if it knew where you wanted it to go).

Many people have a `~/bin` directory (i.e. `bin` in their home directory) and have `$HOME/bin` as part of their `PATH` environment variable.  You can copy (aka "install") the executable there without any root permissions and still have it found by the command line.